# How to handle ActionController::ParameterMissing gracefully

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to handle the error `ActionController::ParameterMissing` gracefully, so instead of returning a ugly HTML, it returns a message and something different than `500 Internal Server Error`.

How know I have this controller:

```
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_metric, only: [:update]

  def update
    if @metric.update(metric_params)
      render json: @metric
    else
      render json: @metric.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_metric
    @metric = Metric.find_by(site: params[:site_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
  end

  def metric_params
    params.require(:metric).permit(:param1, :param2)
  end
end
```

And if I send a request passing other than a json containing a metric key with at least one prop, rails will automatically reply the request with a HTML. I would like to overwrite it.

Comment: potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543840/rails-5-way-to-handle-actioncontrollerparametermissing

Answer (score 0):

This might help [Rails 5 way to handle ActionController::ParameterMissing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543840/rails-5-way-to-handle-actioncontrollerparametermissing)

```
rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing do |e|
  render 'something'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Rails provides a clean way to rescue exceptions in a controller, mapping specific error classes to corresponding handlers.

From https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-rescuable-and-rescue_from/

So, in fact you could use `rescue` or `rescue_from` as Travis mentioned, e.g.

`rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, :with => :render_404`